# Instagram API to remove followers

Tags: python, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Does Instagram provide an API to remove followers?

I am developing an application where users can login with its Instagram account. After login they can select criteria and the followers under that criteria will be removed.

any idea how can I achieve this functionality to remove the followers via API?